# Can't Connect iPad Outlets?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm creating an iPad version of an iPhone app (NOT universal). I created copies of all my .m .h and XIB files, and appended "iPad" to the end of each, as well as to all my classes. This of course was tedious and overly complex but I didn't know a better way.

My problem: When I connect the iPad File's Owner and First Responder to my iPad XIB (see image) Xcode connects the XIB shown below to the **iPhone ViewController code** and *not* the iPad ViewController code.

[image: iPad XIB. When I connect the iPad XIB to the File's Owner and First Responder shown Xcode connects the XIB to my iPhone ViewController class, not the iPad ViewController]

I then went to the code (see below) to see if I could instead connect straight from the code (with those little circles to the left of Outlet code lines) but to no avail. When I click and drag the line and let go over the XIB it doesn't work. It doesn't do anything.
[image: iPad ViewController code. Doesn't connect to the iPad XIB shown at right.]

How do I associate (for lack of a better word) my iPad XIB with my iPad code? The iPad XIB is already part of the target build, FWIW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Click on FileOwner in iPad xib file..
- Go to identity inspector..in the Utilities Section.
- You will see the class name there..Make sure it points to the iPad code class

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've included the correct **File name** in your XIB in the **File Inspector**. This should match the class you are trying to connect objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the class you given for each xib is correct .that is in the identity inspector

Comment: select your file's Owner in IB,then click the identity inspector.You can see which class is currently set.Change that to your ipad viewcontroller class that u required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

File->Reload All Class Files
File->Read Class Files (select MyClass.h)
Reconnect File's Owner by
a. Setting the Class to "MyClass"
b. Reconnecting the View to the File's Owner's View
Everything is back to normal now. Weird.

Hope this helps more than it confuses ;-)